# JSON String upload to PHP with Webclient upload string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

There is code below i would like to achieve to communicate wth php server is:
Unfortunately there is nothing posting to php side (array or single string). var_dump returns null

****added to php to read RAW post data :**now it works

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);**
```

code

```
   private void webClient2_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        MessageBox.Show("ss");
    }
    private void btn_soksok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        StudentName student2 = new StudentName
        {
            f = "Craig",
            l = "Playstead",
        };


       // string datax = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student2);
        string datax = "asdf";
           Uri uri = new Uri("http://XXX.co/up.php");
           WebClient webClient2 = new WebClient();
        //webClient2.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
           webClient2.UploadStringCompleted += webClient2_UploadStringCompleted;

          // webClient2.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
           //webClient2.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";


           webClient2.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", datax);
           MessageBox.Show(datax);

    }
```

class object

```
   public class StudentName {
        public string f { get; set; }
        public string l { get; set; }


    }
```

and php side

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
var_dump($_POST);
$x = json_decode($_POST[0]);
echo $x;
?>
```

Comment: What kind of JSON handling you need to do server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need in your code

```
webClient2.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

and then

```
 string datax = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
 datax = "0=" + datax;
```

in the server I would replace `echo $x;` with `print_r($x);`

Comment: interesting now i can see but why?? i only added this datax = "0=" + datax; i want to upload json btw need json headers

Comment: because post data is like dictionary Key=Value  if the structure is not right, php cannot understand what he received

Comment: how can i upload json string?

Comment: it depends on how the server wants to receive it

Comment: server headers are JSON now, from that point what is needed to send a serialized JSON string, and now everything is null

Comment: These two samples perfectly same whats wrong to handle a json n php?http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-us/6e42c672-ff38-440a-88a3-7e7d7949954b/json-deserialization

Comment: the `header('Content-Type:.......');` is only about how the server answers to the request

Comment: i found it,, it has to read raw data by the server tself $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json); i can see the json now